# wso2am 2.1.0 API export - No enum constant APIDTO.TypeEnum.NULL

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

exporting an API definition through a REST service service I got a following exception:

```
ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper An Unknown exception has been captured by global exception mapper.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.dto.APIDTO.TypeEnum.NULL
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.dto.APIDTO$TypeEnum.valueOf(APIDTO.java:63)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.utils.mappings.APIMappingUtil.fromAPItoDTO(APIMappingUtil.java:239)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisApiIdGet(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:380)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.ApisApi.apisApiIdGet(ApisApi.java:229)
```

If I import an API through the REST APIM API, I can GET / export it. As soon I update the set of resources manually in the publisher (I delete a resource and add another one), this exception occurs.

Thank you all for any hint

Answer (score 2):

It's bug in API manager, it has resolved in issue https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5759. The [pull request](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/4492) has just merged recently, till now, till now there's no official build including this. However you can manually patch it in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some things which seems to be optional need to be defined to make the API exportable, such as parameter description. Specifying a parameter description helped in this case